Memoryless property of the geometric distribution
Proving that for a geometric random variable with probability mass function $(1 - \pi)^{x - 1}\pi$ for $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $0$ otherwise the memorylessness property $\mathbb{P}(X > s + t \; | \; X > s) = \mathbb{P}(X > t)$ holds, my lecturer proceeds as follows:
$$\mathbb{P}(X > s + t \; | \; X > s) = \frac{\sum_{x = s + t + 1}^{\infty}(1 - \pi)^{x - 1}\pi}{\sum_{x = s + 1}^{\infty}(1 - \pi)^{x - 1}\pi} = \frac{\sum_{x = s + t + 1}^{\infty}(1 - \pi)^{x}}{\sum_{x = s + 1}^{\infty}(1 - \pi)^{x}}.$$
I can't really make sense of the change in the exponent of $(1 - \pi)$ unless I suppose my lecturer has changed the index of summation by using, say, $y = x - 1$, and mistakenly left the $x$ variable in the script. Any thoughts?

Hint: multiply the top and the bottom of the fraction by $(1-\pi)$.

Then you can bring it into the summation (it's a constant), so you get indeed $(1 - \pi)^x$? Is that right?

Yes, that is correct

Okay. Thank you.

Here is a detailed, step by step proof.
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[X > s + t \mid X > s]
&= \frac{\Pr[(X > s + t) \cap (X > s)]}{\Pr[X > s]} \\
&= \frac{\Pr[X > s + t]}{\Pr[X > s]} \\
&= \frac{\sum_{x=s+t+1}^\infty (1-\pi)^{x-1} \pi}{\sum_{x=s+1}^\infty (1-\pi)^{x-1} \pi} \\
&= \frac{\sum_{x=s+t+1}^\infty (1-\pi)^{x-1}}{\sum_{x=s+1}^\infty (1-\pi)^{x-1}} \\
&= \frac{\sum_{y=0}^\infty (1-\pi)^{(y+s+t+1)-1}}{\sum_{y=0}^\infty (1-\pi)^{(y+s+1)-1}} \\
&= \frac{\sum_{y=0}^\infty (1-\pi)^{y+s+t}}{\sum_{y=0}^\infty (1-\pi)^{y+s}} \\
&= \frac{\sum_{y=0}^\infty (1-\pi)^y (1-\pi)^{s+t}}{\sum_{y=0}^\infty (1-\pi)^y (1-\pi)^s} \\
&= \frac{(1-\pi)^{s+t} \sum_{y=0}^\infty (1-\pi)^y}{(1-\pi)^s \sum_{y=0}^\infty (1-\pi)^y} \\
&= \frac{(1-\pi)^s (1-\pi)^t}{(1-\pi)^s} \\
&= (1-\pi)^t.
\end{align}$$
With the same technique, we can show
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[X > t] &= \sum_{x=t+1}^\infty (1-\pi)^{x-1} \pi \\
&= \sum_{y=1}^\infty (1-\pi)^{(y+t)-1} \pi \\
&= \sum_{y=1}^\infty (1-\pi)^{y-1+t} \pi \\
&= \sum_{y=1}^\infty (1-\pi)^{y-1} (1-\pi)^t \pi \\
&= (1-\pi)^t \sum_{y=1}^\infty (1-\pi)^{y-1} \pi \\
&= (1-\pi)^t \sum_{y=1}^\infty \Pr[X = y] \\
&= (1-\pi)^t,
\end{align}$$
where we note that the sum of the probabilities of all outcomes of $X$ must equal to $1$.

In fact, it would have been more efficient to start with the evaluation of $\Pr[X > t]$, and then leverage this to compute the conditional probability.  Once you know $\Pr[X > t] = (1-\pi)^t$, then we immediately have
$$\frac{\Pr[X > s+t]}{\Pr[X > s]} = \frac{(1-\pi)^{s+t}}{(1-\pi)^s} = (1-\pi)^t.$$

Many thanks, that was very helpful indeed!
